# Create new DataFrame as ordered mix of columns of other DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, reshape

I have this kind of DataFrames

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1,1.1,1.1], 'b':[2.1,2.1,2.1], 'c':[3.1,3.1,3.1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'aa':[1.2,1.2,1.2], 'bb':[2.2,2.2,2.2], 'cc':[3.2,3.2,3.2]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'aaa':[1.3,1.3,1.3], 'bbb':[2.3,2.3,2.3], 'ccc':[3.3,3.3,3.3]})
```

These frames always have the same shape (and column names doesnt always fit alphabetic order). I want to find out the best way to combine their columns in the resulting frame which looks like:

```
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

My approach is nested loops and filling new frame column by column:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
        df_new[df.columns[i]] = df.iloc[:, i]

print(df_new)
```

It works, but i think there is more reliable way to do this.

**EDIT**: with the help of pd.concat (Thanks @Tbaki) it can be done also woth two steps:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)

small = df1.shape[1]
big = df_new.shape[1]

#create correct order
new_order = []

for i in range(small):
    new_order.extend(list(range(i, big, small)))

df_new.iloc[:, new_order]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [17]: pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1) \
           .loc[:, np.concatenate([t for t in zip(df1.columns,df2.columns,df3.columns)])]
Out[17]:
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

Comment: Brilliant zip idea!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

A bit improved another answer:

```
dfs= [df1,df2,df3]
cols = np.concatenate(list(zip(df1.columns,df2.columns,df3.columns)))
df = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1).reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

Or:

```
from  itertools import chain

dfs= [df1,df2,df3]
cols = chain.from_iterable(list(zip(df1.columns,df2.columns,df3.columns)))
df = pd.concat(dfs,axis=1).reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

Comment: Thank you, but it wont work with real-world column names unfortunately. ill add info in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) then [reindex_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

output

```
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

Comment: Hi! pd.concat helps to concatenate frame-by-frame, i need it to be done column-by-column (a aa aaa b bb bbb c cc ccc) like in my example

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov you want the order to differ in the column name ?

Comment: @AlexeyTrofimov you mean regardless of the column name ?

Comment: Ah i see your editions. Yes, regardless. Its just an example, so sorted(columns) wont work in some cases unfortunately. Ive added one way to do it with your pd.concat idea in start post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dataframe by adding all the columns from the three dataframes in order. This is the solution.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1,1.1,1.1], 'b':[2.1,2.1,2.1], 'c':[3.1,3.1,3.1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'aa':[1.2,1.2,1.2], 'bb':[2.2,2.2,2.2], 'cc':[3.2,3.2,3.2]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'aaa':[1.3,1.3,1.3], 'bbb':[2.3,2.3,2.3], 'ccc':[3.3,3.3,3.3]})

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i,name in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
    df[df1.columns[i]]= df1[df1.columns[i]]
    df[name]= df2[name]
    df[df3.columns[i]]= df3[df3.columns[i]]
print(df)
```

output:

```
     a   aa  aaa    b   bb  bbb    c   cc  ccc
0  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
1  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
2  1.1  1.2  1.3  2.1  2.2  2.3  3.1  3.2  3.3
```

This is the part where you'll be most interested at!

```
for i,name in enumerate(df2.columns.values):
        df[df1.columns[i]]= df1[df1.columns[i]]
        df[name]= df2[name]
        df[df3.columns[i]]= df3[df3.columns[i]]
```

So what I'm basically doing is

`df[df1.columns[i]]= df1[df1.columns[i]]`

Creating a new dataframe with `df[column_name]` where `column_name` would be
`df1.columns[i]` --> `df1.columns[0]` -->`a`

Similarly for,
`df3.columns[i]` --> `df3.columns[0]` -->`aaa`.

However I get column `name` from the second dataframe `df2` using `df2.columns.values`. So in this case

`df[name]= df1[name]`

is enough.